# Tabbing uiTextFields like in simulator

Tags: ios, ios7, uikit, uitextfield

I am building a forms based application and i have noticed that while in the simulator using the hardware mac keyboard i am able to tab between form fields in a table using the standard tab key.

Is there a way i can call this functionality from my TextView when the didReturn method is fired? I have seen numerous threads on here with various ways to achieve something similar but they all seem overly complex and bulky using view tags for big loops which is not ideal compared to perhaps just firing a TAB keyboard command?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set a `nextButton` on your view, or `inputAccessoryView` for all the `textFields` and on `selector` of that button write code to make `nextTextField` a first responder.

By this way you can  implement that tab feature. As you know there's no tab button on your iPhone ;).

Comment: My form is generated within a table view based from a model i have created, at runtime its not clear what the next text field actually is. I could write a bunch of code to track this but thats the bloat i was talking about... Surely the OS is keeping track of this for me as the tab button works in the simulator and i would bet if i used a keyboard with say my iPad...

Comment: You can always add tag to your textFields in accending order while adding those, or in case of tableview indexPath will help you.

Comment: This could get difficult when there are multiple sections, and as i said above the OS seems to already know as pressing tab ion the keyboard tabs through nicely...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via UITextField delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag+1;
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
    if (nextResponder) {
        [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else {
        // Do what ever want to do for last textfield
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Set you textfields tag, sequentially & set delegate. Pressing return key in for moving to next textfield.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: I have a complex hierarchy of controls that are generated at runtime from a model, the controls span various table sections and in varying levels of uiView nesting... having to set a tag and at some level keep track of this is the fluff i was hoping to avoid... The OS clearly knows already as the tab button works...

Comment: Can you discuss more about your complex hierarchy controls? Discuss about your view & process.

Comment: I have a TableView with multiple sections all potentially containing TextFields, the textfields are contained within custom made UIControl sub classes and in some cases TextFields can be within UIviews inside the UIControls.